# Is it possible to have plantuml syntax highlighting in markdown file?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, plantuml

I use VSCode to write markdown files, in which i write plantuml code to have diagrams in my documents. Example:

````
# Hello World

My sequence diagramm

```plantuml
@startuml
Work --> Home
Home --> Work
@enduml
```
````

Visual Studio Code can support plantuml syntax hightlighting (with some extensions). However, the built-in markdown extension does not support plantuml in fenced code block. So we won't have plantuml syntax highlighting within markdown files.

Is it possible to add plantuml support in markdown syntax by extension, or does it require a feature request in VSCode markdown extension ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the plantuml extension or another one can add a new fenced code block language using a grammar injection. I've put together an example of how to do this: https://github.com/mjbvz/vscode-fenced-code-block-grammar-injection-example

Comment: Thank you. Looks like exactly what i was looking for !